# Create temporary file to load in Hive table using stdout redirection

Tags: hadoop, hive, stdout, io-redirection

I would like to create a script to load a tsv file into HIVE.
However since the .tsv file contains an header 
so I first have to create a temporary file without it.

In my script.hql I have the following:

```
DROP TABLE metadata IF EXISTS ;
CREATE TABLE metadata (
    id INT,
    value STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE ;

! tail -n +2 metadata.tsv > tmp_metadata.tsv ;

LOAD DATA LOCAL 'tmp_metadata.tsv' INTO metadata ;
```

The problem is that hive complains about the `>` that should make the redirection to the new fails and therefore the scripts fails.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Create a new shell script named `script.sh` and add this in your shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -n +2 metadata.tsv > tmp_metadata.tsv
hive -v -f ./script.hql
```

**2.** Instead of your `script.hql`:

> **DROP TABLE metadata IF EXISTS** ;
>
> CREATE TABLE metadata (id INT,value STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE ;
>
> ! tail -n +2 metadata.tsv > tmp_metadata.tsv ;
>
> **LOAD DATA LOCAL 'tmp_metadata.tsv' INTO metadata ;**

Add this to your `script.hql`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS metadata;
CREATE TABLE metadata (
    id INT,
    value STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE ;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'tmp_metadata.tsv' INTO TABLE metadata ;
```

`DROP TABLE metadata IF EXISTS ;` is not correct. Change it to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS metadata;`

and

`LOAD DATA LOCAL 'tmp_metadata.tsv' INTO metadata ;`  is not correct. Change it to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'tmp_metadata.tsv' INTO TABLE metadata ;`

**3.** Now, change permission for your shell script and execute it:

```
sudo chmod 777 script.sh
./script.sh
```